# Using jQuery to show div based on selection but include seniority?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have six divs:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
<div class="six"></div>
```

When the user clicks on any of the divs, the class .active gets added to the divs. I need to display a value depending on which divs have the .active class. For example, if the divs "one and two" have the active class than I want to display the value "1". If the div with the class three or four also has the active class than I was to display the value "2". If the div with the class five or six has the class active than I want to display the value "3".

What I can't figure out is how to display the value "3" when div five or six has the class active, no matter what other divs have the active class. For example, if divs one, two, and five have the active class than I want to display 3. I tried an if else statement like this:

```
if ($('.one').hasClass('active') || $('.two').hasClass('active') ) {
 alert(1);
} else if ( $('.three').hasClass('active') || $('.four').hasClass('active') {
 alert(2);
else if ( $('.five').hasClass('active') || $('.six').hasClass('active') ) {
 alert(3)
}
```

the problem I am running into is that if div one and six both have the class active than value 1 will show when I want value 3 to show.

I'm sure I gave a horrible explanation of the problem so please ask me to clarify I need to.

Comment: Don't use `else` if you want each test to be independent of the previous ones.

Comment: Or if the last test is to take priority, do that test first.

Comment: just reverse the order of your if else